# Set Different Typography for Joomla Template

Tags: templates, joomla, themes, joomla3.0, joomla-template

It is possible to add different typography for different home pages in the Joomla template. I want to set different typography according to home page selection. possible how?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different [page class suffix](https://docs.joomla.org/Page_Class_Suffix) in the menu option for each page and then use the page class suffixes in [custom CSS](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) to specify the typography for each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the typography for the content area, use **"Page Class"** in **"Page Display"** Tab inside your menu item.

If you want to change the typography for the entire menu item page, try this:

- By item id:

As an example in the default *Protostar* template you can see in the `<body>` tag a class like:

```
<body class="... itemid-101 ...">
```

This corresponds to the menu item with the Id 101. From here you can add a class in the file [user.css](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_a_custom_CSS_with_Protostar) for the new CSS class `.item101 {}`, this works for the entire `<body>` tag.

The code used here, in the index.php file:

`<?php echo $itemid ? ' itemid-' . $itemid : ''; ?>`

- You also can use similar approach with an active menu item, find here more examples:
  https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Page_Class_Suffix_in_Template_Code